# Style Property and Values

Tags: c#, puppeteer, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

I am extracting name and values of each element in `HTML` `DOM`. For style attribute able to extract only property names not values.

My code is given below:

```
var elementHandles = await page.QuerySelectorAllAsync("a");
    foreach (var handle in elementHandles)
    {
        var elementStyle = await handle.GetPropertyAsync("style");
        var style = await elementStyle.JsonValueAsync();
        var output = style.ToString();
    }
```

This is my output:

```
{{
  "0": "font-family",
  "1": "font-size",
  "2": "line-height",
  "3": "color",
  "4": "text-align"
}}
```

This is what I am expecting:

```
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: 12px; 
line-height: 16px; 
color: #999999;
text-align: left
```

Comment: Give some more detail. Its not enough and cannot understand which problem you are getting.

Comment: @UsmanKhan   
  I have an 5 anchor elements in DOM   
  e.g. <a style="font-family:Aril, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 16px; color: #999999;text-align: left" href="http://view.email.com/ target="_blank">click here</a>
  I am reading attributes of this element in PuppeteerSharp. Above code is not extracting css class name and its value e.g. "font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" 
  instead returning "0": "font-family"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is how the `CSSStyleDeclaration` is serialized. If that´s how Chromium decides to serialize that object there is nothing we can do there.

But, we can try to solve that from javascript using `EvaluateFunctionAsync`.

```cs
foreach (var handle in elementHandles)
{
  var style = await page.EvaluateFunctionAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>(
    "e => Object.entries(e.style).filter(i => isNaN(i[0]) && i[1]).map(i => { return { [i[0]] : i[1]}}).reduce((acc, cur) => { return {...acc, ...cur}}, {})", handle);
  var output = style.ToString();
}
```

Let's take a look at the javascript expression

```js
e=> //We send the HTML element instead of the style property
  Object.entries(e.style) //We get all the property/value pairs from the CSSStyleDeclaration object
    // We want to exclude number properties (like 0,1,2) and empty values
    .filter(i => isNaN(i[0]) && i[1]) 
    //We turn them into objects
    .map(i => { return { [i[0]] : i[1]}})
    //We merge them into one single object that will be returned to C#
    .reduce((acc, cur) => { return {...acc, ...cur}}, {})
```